# failed to connect to mongolab using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to connect to a mongolab DB like this:
`mongoose.connect('mongodb://ronen:123456@ds057528.mongolab.com:57528/ronendb');`

But I'm always getting the error: 
`MongoDB connection error: 
[Error: failed to connect to [ds057528.mongolab.com:57528]]`

What can be the problem?

Comment: Is the port open? telnet ds057528.mongolab.com 57528 to see what happens

Comment: thanks @yaoxing. That was the problem.